# When did the Soviets get the ability to drop a nuclear bomb on the United States?

Tags: united-states, soviet-union, cold-war

I'm researching the history of the Cold War and I have the impression that the Soviets failed to develop a bomber capable of flying from Russia to the United States until 1956, when the [Tu-95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-95) bomber entered service. The [R-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-7_Semyorka) ICBM was developed in 1957.

If this is correct, then

- the Russians developed a nuclear bomb in 1949, but
- it was useless as a weapon against the US until 1956 because they couldn't drop the bomb on America (they had the bomb, but no suitable means of transportation).

At what point in time did the USSR get the ability to nuke the major areas in the US (i. e. bomb plus aircraft or rocket to deliver it from Russia to the US) ?

By "major areas" I mean big cities and important military objects.

Comment: Russia to Alaska is 55miles. I'm guessing they had a bomber that could fly that far in 1949.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the question -- I'm interested at what point in time they could drop a bomb on New York, Washington and other major cities.

Comment: @KillingTime: what would one bomb in Alaska?

Comment: Alaska was not a U.S. state (only a "territory") until 1959.

Comment: Vladivostok to Seoul is a _very_ short distance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

(Revised) In principle, they obtained this capability in 1951.

In 1949 the Soviets introduced Tu-4 (an unlicensed copy of B-29, by "reverse engineering") with range 5400 km and 847 of them were built in 1949-1952. It was the first Soviet aircraft capable to drop nuclear weapon. With this range it could reach major US cities without return.

The Soviets were prompt in demonstration of this capability. Tu-4 was shown to the world in an aviation demonstration in August 1947 (4 of them appeared).

The next model was Tu-16 (1500 built starting 1954) with range 7200 km,
already sufficient to hit NY from Murmansk region.
The first Soviet airplane which could reach NY City and return was Tu-95 (first flight in November 1952, deployed since 1957) which is still used by Russia.

However, Yuly Khariton in his memoirs mentions that the first air dropped
bomb was tested in October 1951, from Tu-4. (The earlier bombs were not designed for air drop).

Another reference addressing exactly this question is
CIA. Special National Intelligence Estimate. Soviet Capabilities for Attack on the US through 1957. SNIE 11–2-54, published February 24, 1954. P. 5–6. HSTL, PSF.

EDIT2. A good source is the book of David Holloway, Stalin and the bomb. He cites the following dialog about M-4 bomber by Miasishchev (1954):
"When Khrushchev expressed his dissatisfaction with M-4 having no sufficient range, Miasishchev replied that the plane can bomb in the US and then land in Mexico. Khrushchev: Do you consider Mexico our mother-in-law!? Whom you can visit at any time? Mexicans will never return our plane".

Very typical of Khrushchev:-)

BTW Holloway estimated that SU had only 50 nuclear bombs by 1954.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. *reach major US cities without return.*: Does it mean the pilot would be sort of Kamikaze pilot (i. e. die with the plane) ?

Comment: @FranzDrollig, it would not be quite that suicidal. Depending on the remaining fuel, the crew could fly towards an allied or neutral country, towards open ocean where a ship would pick them up after ditching the plane, or at least beyond the immediate blast radius to parachute down. In theory, even a crew that had just nuked a city could surrender and become POWs. The US used similar tactics in their emergency war plans.

Comment: @FranzDrollig: The whole crew (a Tu-4 had a normal crew of 11) would be unable to return. Depending on the route and its length they might be able to reach somewhere friendly, or at least land or parachute somewhere they hadn't just nuked. For example, an mission to New York from Murmansk might well be able to reach Cuba.

Comment: @JohnDallman, Cuba wasn't socialist at the time in question.

Comment: The fate of the crew is a minor consideration in the nuclear strike planning. There are many options: land somewhere and surrender lend on a neutral territory etc.

Comment: Of course this assumes that the bombers could get to the US undetected, and wouldn't be shot down.  In practice, the US had quite sophisticated (for the time) detection and intercept capabilites, such as the SAGE program and DEW line.

Comment: @jamesqf Sophisticated, but [not necessarily very effective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Skyshield). (OK, that was a bit later, though one would expect both defensive and offensive capabilities to have improved by then.)

Comment: Having a nuclear device and a bomber is not enough. The answer assumes that the Soviet nuke design of 1949 could be transported by Tu-4, which is by no means a given. The first nukes (US and Soviet) were very large.

Comment: The first Soviet atomic bomb, RDS-1, was extremely similar to the "Fat Man" bomb dropped on Nagasaki from a B-29, so it's likely that it could have been carried by a Tu-4. A 1951 test, RDS-3, was air-dropped. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_atomic_bomb_project

Comment: @jamesqf The theory at the time, believed by all, was that "The bomber will always get through." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_bomber_will_always_get_through What it really means is, at least 1 bomber will reach the target. It came from WW2 experience. Ignore hollywood showing huge formations of bombers all getting blasted. In reality, more like 5, 10%, maybe 25%, did not come back from a sortie. Simply **detecting** the incoming squadrons is good for warning time, but is by no means a guarantee of stopping them. So if you wanna analyze capability, you really hafta look at fleet numbers.

Comment: @DrZ214: You need to remember that those WWII bomber formations were going up against opponents without much in the way of effective radar, and at a much shorter operational distance, so that - worst case - there simply wouldn't be time for the air defenses to handle all the bombers.  The "bomber will always get through" is contingency thinking, just as an attacker has to think about what happens if they all do get shot down.

Comment: @jamesqf: One bomber with one bomb is not enough to in a war. You can see on Wikipedia that the 847 Tu-4 were built in 1949-52, and the 1500 Tu-16 were built 1954-62.

Comment: @Alex: Exactly.  One bomber, or a few bombers, may get through, but to win the war you have to get enough bombers through to effectively destroy the enemy.  Or demoralize them through shock, as with Japan, but the problem is that that approach only works once.

Comment: @jamesqf: WW II Germany **did** have [significant radar capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_in_World_War_II#Germany).

Comment: @DevSolar: They had the capability, but didn't use it effectively (at least according to what I've read).  From your link "...it appears radar received a much lower priority until later in World War II; by the start of the war, few had been fielded."

Comment: @jamesqf: Those up-to-25% loss rates were inflicted mid-war, when the USA was already involved but before the Luftwaffe effectively collapsed.

Comment: A chinese general, when asked about why China has less bombs than the USA, answered that the threat of obliterating a few large cities is enough as deterrent. The USSR did not think in this way, but as far as propaganda goes, the same reasoning might apply, and IRL, it has some merit, until the USSR had enough bombs to go full MAD.